# Error while upgrading Magento 2.2.6 to 2.3.1

Tags: magento2

Now the magento version is 2.2.6 target version is 2.3.1 :

steps we have followed to upgrade :

http://magefoo.com/upgrade-magento-from-2.2.6-to-2.3.0/

In the 8th step i.e 'composer update' the error happens :

Current PHP version is 7.0.3 while using this version no error but composer hangs at updating dependencies

I updated the PHP version to 7.1.9 then at composer update step the error happens is :

```
Problem 1
 - The requested package friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer (locked at v2.2.20, required as ~2.10.0) is satisfiable by friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer[v2.2.20] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
Problem 2
 - The requested package sebastian/phpcpd (locked at 2.0.4, required as ~3.0.0) is satisfiable by sebastian/phpcpd[2.0.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
Problem 3
 - magento/framework 100.0.20 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.0.19 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.0.18 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.0.17 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.0.16 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.0.15 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.0.14 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.0.13 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.0.12 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.0.11 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.0.10 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.0.9 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.0.8 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.0.7 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.0.6 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.0.5 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.0.4 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - magento/framework 100.0.3 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - magento/framework 100.0.2 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - magento/framework 100.1.15 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - magento/framework 100.1.14 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.1.13 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - magento/framework 100.1.12 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - magento/framework 100.1.11 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - magento/framework 100.1.10 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - magento/framework 100.1.9 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - magento/framework 100.1.8 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - magento/framework 100.1.7 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - magento/framework 100.1.6 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - magento/framework 100.1.5 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.1.4 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.1.3 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.1.2 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.1.1 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - magento/framework 100.1.0 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.1.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
 - php-cuong/magento2-regions-manager 2.2.1 requires magento/framework 100.0.*|100.1.*|101.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.6, 100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.1.0, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.1.1, 100.0.12, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.0.13, 100.1.4, 100.0.14, 100.1.5, 100.0.15, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 100.0.18, 101.0.0, 100.0.19, 101.0.1, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 101.0.2, 100.0.20, 100.1.12, 101.0.3, 100.1.13, 101.0.4, 101.0.5, 100.1.14, 100.1.15, 100.1.16, 101.0.7, 100.1.17, 101.0.8, 100.1.18, 101.0.9].
  - php-cuong/magento2-regions-manager 2.2.1 requires magento/framework 100.0.*|100.1.*|101.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.6, 100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.1.0, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.1.1, 100.0.12, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.0.13, 100.1.4, 100.0.14, 100.1.5, 100.0.15, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 100.0.18, 101.0.0, 100.0.19, 101.0.1, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 101.0.2, 100.0.20, 100.1.12, 101.0.3, 100.1.13, 101.0.4, 101.0.5, 100.1.14, 100.1.15, 100.1.16, 101.0.7, 100.1.17, 101.0.8, 100.1.18, 101.0.9].
   - php-cuong/magento2-regions-manager 2.2.1 requires magento/framework 100.0.*|100.1.*|101.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.6, 100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.1.0, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.1.1, 100.0.12, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.0.13, 100.1.4, 100.0.14, 100.1.5, 100.0.15, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 100.0.18, 101.0.0, 100.0.19, 101.0.1, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 101.0.2, 100.0.20, 100.1.12, 101.0.3, 100.1.13, 101.0.4, 101.0.5, 100.1.14, 100.1.15, 100.1.16, 101.0.7, 100.1.17, 101.0.8, 100.1.18, 101.0.9].
  - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.1, 101.0.6].
 - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.1, 101.0.0].
 - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.1, 101.0.1].
 - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.1, 101.0.2].
 - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.1, 101.0.3].
 - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.1, 101.0.4].
 - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.1, 101.0.5].
 - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.1, 101.0.6].
 - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.1, 101.0.7].
 - Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.8, 102.0.1].
 - Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.9, 102.0.1].
 - Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.6, 102.0.1].
 - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.1, 100.1.16].
 - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.1, 100.1.17].
 - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.18, 102.0.1].
 - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.1 requires magento/framework 102.0.1 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.1].
 - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.1].
 - Installation request for php-cuong/magento2-regions-manager (locked at 2.2.1, required as *) -> satisfiable by php-cuong/magento2-regions-manager[2.2.1].
```

After that I tried

```
   composer update --lock
```

then the errors is

[image]

How should i solve this issues and upgrade my magento version(2.2.6) to the version 2.3.1 ??
Please do respond if anyone knows the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your composer.json file should look a bit like this

https://github.com/DominicWatts/magento2-mirror/blob/2.3.1/composer.json

```
"require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.13.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "~2.3.13",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.3.1",
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
```

Run `composer install`

Can always use the `--no-dev` param to skip the dev requires

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,But its still Not Working Same Error Happening again...

Comment: @HakeemPA just for the sake of getting it down have you tried using the `--ignore-platform-reqs` param.  Obviously do this on a test site first.

Comment: Not working...Same Error Happening again...